# If I have Java 7 Updates 4 & 5 both installed, I can delete the earlier one, correct?

Tags: java, uninstall

Also have JavaFX 2.1.1 installed, if that's relevant. Windows 7 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely remove older versions of Java.  Some applications do require a specific version of Java to be installed, but those are not common.  And the worst case is you just have to download it again.